# How to replace raw urls inside paragraphs to html links using regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to change absolute url within a paragraph:

```
<p>http://www.google.com</p>
```

into html link into paragraph:

```
<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a></p>
```

Thare can be a lot of paragraphs. I want the regex to cut out the generic `url` value from this: `<p>url<p>`, and put it into template like this: `<p><a href=\"url\">url</a></p>`

How to do it in the short way ? Can it be done using regex.Replace() method ?

BTW: Regular expression used for absolute urls matching can be like this: `^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$` (taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx))

Comment: Avoid using a regex on HTML.  Have a look at this question for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the clue. But this will be actually used aganist not too long html code so regex usage this should be here an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this regex:

```
(?<!\")(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?(?!\")
```

to avoid matching `<a href="http://www.google.com">` like strings(enclosed by`"`).

And a sample code:

```
var inputString = @"<p>http://www.google.com</p><p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">my web link</a></p>";
var pattern = @"(?<url>(?<!\")(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?(?!\"))";
var result = Regex.Replace(strInput, pattern, "<a href=\"${url}\">${url}</a>");
```

explain:

***`(?<!subexpression)`*** `Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.`

***`(?!subexpression)`*** `Zero-width negative lookahead assertion.`

***`(?<name>subexpression)`*** `Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.`

Answer (score 0):

form your regex: remove first ^ and last $ - it means "match the whole input string from start to end"

```
string regexPattern = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?";

string input = @"<p>http://www.google.com</p>";

var reg = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// $0 - substitution, refers to  the text matched by the whole pattern    
var output = reg.Replace(input, "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

more about substitutions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx